# Problem with Chunksize and concat. ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

I can't compile the following code. I know that the part of the code that it prints could be inside the loop below, but I want to understand why it does not compile the way it is written. Thank you.

The csv file can be downloaded from the "Minerando Dados" repository (https://github.com/minerandodados/mdrepo)

```
import pandas as pd

arquivo = 'kc_house_data.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(arquivo, nrows = 7)
chunk = pd.read_csv(arquivo, chunksize = 5000)

for parte in chunk:
  print(len(parte))

lista = []
for parte in chunk:
    lista.append(parte['floors']*3)
  
dataset['floors_size'] = pd.concat(lista)
```

ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `chunk` is a generator, the generator will become empty once you did this

```
for parte in chunk:
    print(len(parte))
```

The simplest solution is to delete the for loop that print the lengths of the dataframes. However, a faster solution is

```
arquivo = 'kc_house_data.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(arquivo, nrows = 7)
chunk = pd.read_csv(arquivo, chunksize = 5000)

dataset['floors_size'] = pd.concat(chunk,ignore_index=True)['floors'] * 3
```